# HttpClient How to post data by custom size like 1MB per second when uploading a file

Tags: c#, networking, file-upload, buffer, httpclient

I upload files by HttpClient and there is a problem when uploading big file larger than 20GB, it uses my whole network traffic and sometimes router/switch falls down and requires manual reset.
So I need to limit uploading by buffer size like 1MB per second. How to do it?
My current code is below:

```
ProgressMessageHandler progress = new ProgressMessageHandler();
progress.HttpSendProgress += ProgressEventHandler;
progress.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(progress))
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    string url = "https://www.exameple.com/upload_webapi";
    Uri baseUri = new Uri(url);
    client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

    string username = "user";
    string password = "pass";
    var authenticationString = $"{username}:{password}";
    var base64EncodedAuthenticationString = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authenticationString));

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
    content.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", Path.GetFileName(path));
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/UploadFile");
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);
    requestMessage.Content = content;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    using (var task = client.SendAsync(requestMessage))
    {
        var response = task.Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string str = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (str.Trim() == "")
                str = response.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
}
```

On server side, there is a webapi gets uploading file in form-data